# 'm a' vs 'm ()' in guard

Tags: haskell, monads

```
guard :: (MonadPlus m) => Bool -> m ()
guard True  = return ()
guard False = mzero

Prelude Control.Monad> :t mzero
mzero :: (MonadPlus m) => m a
```

In the False branch of `guard`, the type of `mzero` is `m a`, but the return type of `guard` has been specified as `m ()`. Hence I don't quite get it why compiler won't complain about this.

I mean if `mzero` returns a value typed as `Maybe Int`, which is, of course, different from `Maybe ()`, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler won't complain because `m a` is a superset of `m ()`.

Comment: 'mzero' can return something like 'Maybe Int', right? I think it's different from 'Maybe ()'

Comment: @aXqd: For the Maybe monad, `mzero = Nothing`, which has no preferred type for `a`. If you indeed cast `Nothing` to `Maybe Int`, it is different from `Maybe ()`. However, the type is `Maybe a` for any possible `a`, not `Maybe Int`, so `Maybe ()` is valid.

Comment: @KennyTM Thanks for your reply. Yes, I might use a bad example. However if I write a custom type - 'MyType', and then make it the instance of 'Monad' and 'MonadPlus'. I can make 'mzero' return 'MyType Int' then. In fact, I think if there's a chance that what is going to be returned by 'mzero' is not 'm ()', the compiler should complain about it. Because the type of 'mzero' and the return type of 'guard' don't match with each other. I know I am wrong on this conclusion. I'm just not sure where the problem is. :P

Comment: @aXqd: If `mzero` returns `MyType Int` then `mzero` is implemented incorrectly. The MonadPlus instance *must* implement `mzero` to return `MyType a` regardless of what `a` is. In fact, it won't compile if you try to return a `MyType Int`. (http://www.ideone.com/lcXYn)

Comment: @KennyTM Oh, I didn't expect this. I think I finally got it. 'mzero' is typed as 'm a', hence it cannot be implemented to return some concrete type as 'm Int'. So the only possible type returned by 'mzero' is abstract type 'm a', which can match perfectly with 'm ()'. Thanks. :D

Comment: In a contrary manner, it's OK. For example, 'Nothing :: Maybe ()'

Comment: In other words, `mzero`  must be able to return `m a` for any `a`, of the _CALLER_'s choice.  This is because a "free" type variable like `a` has an implicit "for all `a`", whereas in the Java/C++ tradition, a type like `Object` has an implicit "there exists some type `t` that is a subclass of `Object`", and which type it actually is is the choice of whoever provided that object.  The default "sense" of polymorphism is the opposite in Haskell from what it is in more "object oriented" languages.

Comment: Some of this comment stuff should probably be in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `mzero :: (MonadPlus m) => m a` is a bit of short-hand for `forall (a :: *) (m :: * -> *). MonadPlus m => m a`, meaning for **any choice** of type constructor `m` and type `a`, if just the restriction that `m` is an instance of the `MonadPlus` typeclass is satisfied, `mzero` can be at that type.

The type of `guard`, similarly, is `forall (m :: * -> *). MonadPlus m => Bool -> m ()`. In `guard False = mzero`, the type of the `mzero` on the right-hand side must thus be `m ()` for any appropriate choice of `m`. By choosing `a` to be `()` and `m` to be the requested monad, `mzero`'s type, itself becomes `m ()` which is exactly what `guard` needs to return.

Comment: That used to be the type of `guard`. Now it's `guard :: Alternative f => Bool -> f ()`. I figure a new answer should reflect the new type.